# how to impose binarity constraint in a vector

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, integer-programming

This is part of a homework problem. In an optimization problem, I need to have a K dimensional vector S, such that each entry of the vector is either 0 or 1, and $l_1$ norm of S is <= K. I can't find a way to write this in a succinct way. Any help?

Comment: If you have constraints like this, it **cannot** be a  convex optimization problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about $S\in\{0,1\}^K,\,\|S\|_1 \leq K$?

And, BTW, the former condition implies the latter, so you just need

$S\in\{0,1\}^K$.

Comment: but how do I include the first requirement with another equation of the form ||WS-b||<M,

Comment: @rivu Sorry, I did not understand the question, could you make it more clear? What do you mean by including the first requirement with another equation?

Comment: So, the optimization equation is the form ||WS-b||<M. The constraint imposed on S should be that it's binary. The other constraint follows naturally.

Comment: Oh, then you may write, for example $\min_{S\in\{0,1\}^K} \|WS-b\|$

Comment: Yes, I could write that, but that would be hard to solve, right? If I could write the constraint as a function of S (say norm), I could try to form a lagrangian or similar things.

Comment: With your binary condition, you cannot use a Lagrangian approach.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

\begin{align}
\min_{x\in \Re^k}\quad& \|Wx-b\|\\
&\|x\|_1\leq K\\
&x_i^2=x_i \qquad\forall i
\end{align}

This isn't convex since the equality constraint isn't linear but this shouldn't be too hard to solve. Did you specifically want convex constraints?

Comment: Oh this is nice and what I wanted. I am still not accepting it because it would be nice if anyone can write a convex constraint.

Comment: There *is no* convex constraint. Cannot be done.